# Cannot open file 'glew32.lib'

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2012

I have downloaded glew-1.9.0.zip built the projects under C:\glew-1.9.0\build\vc6 and C:\glew-1.9.0\build\vc10 and am unable to build after setting visual studio's paths to the glew include and lib paths. The lib directory does NOT have glew32.lib after building glew. What must I do in order to be able to build an opengl project?

Comment: Compiling successed, without errors?

Answer (score 6):

You could download binary pack ([32 bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/glew/files/glew/1.9.0/glew-1.9.0-win32.zip/download) or [64 bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/glew/files/glew/1.9.0/glew-1.9.0-win64.zip/download)) and find already compiled version of **glew32.lib** in lib folder and all includes?:)

In your OpenGL project open Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker ->  Input -> Additional Dependencies -> add **glew32.lib**.

Also you must include `#include <GL/glew.h>` in your sources;
For that add path to your glew folder: Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properies -> General -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories and Library Directories;

Comment: Everything @Edward83 says + move glew32.lib from glew-1.10.0\lib\Release\Win32 to glew-1.10.0\lib and paste glew32.dll from glew-1.10.0\bin\Release\Win32 to directory with destination executable of your project (for me it is: Documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Debug)

Comment: That's the real solution! Thank you so much :D